# What is the Web3 approach to storing secret tokens (for example, when need to store the local salt for commit/reveal pattern)?

Tags: solidity, metamask, dapp-design, design-patterns

What is the Web3 approach to storing secret tokens (for example, when need to store the local salt for commit/reveal pattern)?

I'm currently using local storage.

For example in Web2 a back-end layer for storing tokens is used. What is the proper approach to storing local salt value in Web3?

Maybe there's a way to store it in the local wallet like Metamask? Like a Metamask password manager, I'm not sure if there're any solutions for that.

Please advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage is not designed for sensitive data as it is stored in plain text and has a simple domain access policy. With different attack vectors like XSS, MitB, or physical access, the data can be retrieved. Without a backend layer, your best option is to encode the data before storing it in local storage.

Use [WebAuthn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API) to get the key for encryption via user's biometric and utilize [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) for secure encryption before storing.

> Those are the best options you can employ to secure the tokens locally. However, regarding your example, local storage may be sufficient to store the salt for the commit/reveal pattern, depending on your business logic. Unless users device is not compromised and there is a short period between commitment and revealing data.

> You could use accounts pub key to encrypt data with  [`eth_getencryptionpublickey`](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/eth_getencryptionpublickey/) and then use [`eth_decrypt`](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/eth_decrypt/) to decrypt. But it **doesn't work on mobile devices** and **not in every** other wallet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense!! My salt is intended to be used not later than 5 minutes after generation. I'll look into the links you referenced.